# Why doesn't ld search rpaths from a DSO itself at link time

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, ld

I have libA.so, libB.so, and an executable 'foo'. 'foo' needs libB.so which itself needs libA.so. During linking foo explicitly links with libB because it directly uses symbols from it. 'foo' does not directly use symbols from libA. When linking 'foo', ld wants to check it can resolve symbols references from libB in libA but it can't find libA. I can make it find libA by using -Wl,rpath-link=, or I can have the linker ignore libA using -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined.

The problem is I shouldn't have to set either of these options because libB.so contains an rpath that tells the linker where to find libA.so and the linker uses this rpath at runtime to successfully find libA. So why doesn't it use it at link time? Forcing foo's build configuration to know where libA is seems completely unnecessary in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I shouldn't have to set either of these options because libB.so contains an rpath that tells the linker where to find libA.so and the linker uses this rpath at runtime

You are mixing up the static linker `ld` and the runtime linker (aka loader) `ld.so`.

On Linux, these come from binutils and GLIBC respectively. They are *completely* different programs, maintained by different sets of people.

It would be possible for `ld` to implement the search path that *current* version of `ld.so` uses, but this is

- nontrivial amount of code, that would need to be written from scratch and
- will break as soon as `ld.so` search mechanism is changed

**Update:**

> isn't the search of the rpath executed by the dynamic linker 'the standard'

There is no standard that defines this (that I know of).

In addition, on Linux and Solaris the search path that `ld.so` uses could contain dynamic tokens like `$ORIGIN` and `$PLATFORM`, which are *unknown* at (static) link time.

Comment: I see, thanks. But isn't the search of the rpath executed by the dynamic linker 'the standard', so if ld can't find a library that ld.so can find then its just a bug in ld. (Complexity of implementing the bug/feature doesn't affect its correctness).